# Update query is not updating data in PHP mysqli (procedural)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am facing issues with `id='$id'`
SELECT Query is working fine but update query is not working
if I put any id number instead of `$id` it updates the data but when I use `$id` it just does nothing.

```
<?php 

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "aashir");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id='$id' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $key = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['student_name'];
        $fname = $row['father_name'];
        $program = $row['student_program'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
    $s_fname = $_POST['s_fname'];
    $s_program = $_POST['s_program'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE students SET student_name = '$s_name', father_name = '$s_fname', student_program = '$s_program' WHERE id='$id' ";
    mysqli_query($db, $query2);

    header("Location:show.php");
}
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Edit Student</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">

    <form method="POST" action="edit.php" class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
      <h2 class="text-center">Edit a Student</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="s_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="s_fname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="s_program" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $program; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.** (O'Leary)

Comment: Mysql fails differently than regular PHP. Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) if your query does not work like you think it should.

Comment: enable error reporting also. You're trying to assign something to the query that doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options to fix your issue (without talking about SQL injection, already quoted in the comments and to be addressed since it is a huge security risk for your application)

Change the form action to pass the id to the page while processing the form:

```
action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"
```

or better add an hidden input with the id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

and then:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
    $s_fname = $_POST['s_fname'];
    $s_program = $_POST['s_program'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
```

in this case the action can remain the same.
Posting the form you are reloading the page and not passing the id anymore via url as at the first load

Answer (score -1):

You're performing the `UPDATE` using a POST request, yet you're looking for `$id` as a GET parameter. This way, `$id` will always be undefined, and thus the query fails.

You can try overloading the form action URL, like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
```

Comment: It would be better to add it as a hidden field, so as to not confuse POST and GET variables.

Comment: @aynber, no, a hidden field would be posted in the POST body data, and the problem would then persist. However the id is made persistent, is up to the poster. I think what matters is to understand why the problem was there.